# How to pop queue if using vector as container

Tags: c++

I am learning queue in STL, and then thought to try other containers that i can use to implement queue.

So i used vector as a container but in MSVS for pop function

```
queue<int, vector<int>> q;
q.push(1); 
q.push(2);
q.pop();
cout << q.front() << " ";
```

i was getting error
C2039 'pop_front' is not a member of 'std::vector>

C2056 illegal expression (it points to pop function in queue header file)

So is there any other way to pop a element when we change containers?

Comment: No i mean pop() for poping the front element of queue.

Comment: A container for `std::queue` must provide, among others, `pop_front` member function. Which is not the case of `std::vector`. See, for example, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue.

Comment: `std::vector` doesn't match requirements for `std::queue`'s container. The only two standard containers that meet requirements are `std::deque` and `std::list`.

Comment: You can inherit from queue, and provide overloaded `pop` function in which you modify underlying `this->c` container, for example for vector calling `erase` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::queue` requires that the underlying container be a [SequenceContainer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/SequenceContainer) and also supply the

- `back()`
- `front()`
- `push_back()`
- `pop_front()`

member functions.  `std::vector` does not have `pop_front` as that is an O(N) operations so you cannot use it as the underlying container.  You either need to use your own vector class that has these functions or switch to using a different container that does have these functions.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use `std::vector` as a container for `std::queue`. The only acceptable *standard* containers are `std::deque` and `std::list`. (PS: you can create your own container which meets these requirements.)

Referece: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/

> The underlying container shall support at least the following operations:

- `empty`
- `size`
- `front`
- `back`
- `push_back`
- `pop_front`